# Why type need to be specified manually in this code, in rust?

Tags: rust, trait-bounds

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=981f0d0192017bc395d394866b43d2da)

```rust
trait B<T> {}
impl<T> B<T> for T {}

fn f<K>()
where
    // u32: B<u32>, // 4
    u32: B<K>, // 3
{
    // get::<u32>(&1u32); // 2
    get(&1u32); // 1 error
}

fn get<Q>(k: &Q)
where
    u32: B<Q>,
{
}

fn main() {}
```

error at 1:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:10:9
   |
4  | fn f<K>()
   |      - expected this type parameter
...
10 |     get(&1u32); // 1 error
   |     --- ^^^^^ expected `&K`, found `&u32`
   |     |
   |     arguments to this function are incorrect
   |
   = note: expected reference `&K`
              found reference `&u32`
```

However, `&u32` also satisfy trait bound of `get`.

if I change 1 to 2, it is OK.

if I remove 3, it is OK.

if I add 4, it is OK.

Why?

Comment: Please post the **full** error from `cargo check`, **not** your IDE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a case of a somewhat less-known detail of Rust's inference: *if there are two possible method candidates, and one of them comes from a trait bound of the function (and the other does not), Rust prefers the trait bound's method, unless explicitly told otherwise*.

In your case, there are two possible candidates for `get::<_>(&u32)` (written as `get(&1u32)`) in the generic parameter `Q`. The first is to choose `Q = u32`, the second being `Q = K`. Since the method requires `u32: B<Q>`, even though both satisfy this bound, `Q = K` is selected, because it comes from a trait bound in the caller method, while `Q = u32` comes from the environment (the impl `impl<T> B<T> for T`).

This special case is done to aid inference in cases like the following:

```rust
fn foo<T: Into<String>>(v: T) {
    let s = v.into();
}
```

Here, the programmer obviously wants `s` to have type `String`. However, there are actually two candidates here: one being `<T as Into<String>>::into()`, but the other is the reflexive impl `<T as Into<T>>::into()`, provided by std. In order for this to not be ambiguous, Rust prefers the trait bound unless explicitly told otherwise.