Rust Borrow Checker Issues
I need some help figuring out the Rust borrow checker. The following is a minimal example of the problem I'm facing:
struct VecMutRef<'a> {
    vec: &'a mut Vec<usize>,
}

trait Length {
    fn len(&self) -> usize;
}

impl<'a> Length for VecMutRef<'a> {
    fn len(&self) -> usize {
        self.vec.len()
    }
}

fn f<'a>(v: &'a mut Vec<usize>) -> usize
where
    VecMutRef<'a>: Length,
{
    let first = g(v);
    let second = g(v);
    first + second
}

fn g<'a>(v: &'a mut Vec<usize>) -> usize
where
    VecMutRef<'a>: Length,
{
    let vec = VecMutRef { vec: v };
    vec.len()
}

The compiler complains that I cannot borrow *v twice in the function f. I was thinking by the time the first call to the function g is returned, it's done with the mutable reference to v, so I'm free to mutably borrow *v again. But apparently, that's not the case. It would be great if someone could explain to me what's wrong and suggest a possible workaround. I understand that in this particular example, I don't need a mutable reference to Vec just to get its length. The example is just for an illustrative purpose.

This looks like a case of a compiler bug where a constraint makes it short sighted. It seems to think that because 'a satisfies the constraint in f that is also used in g that it must use the original 'a in the nested calls even when a shorter lifetime would work. This is evident since removing the full where clause from f makes it compile.

Using for<'b> VecMutRef<'b>: Length also fixes the error.

@kmdreko Should this bug be reported (or is it already reported)?

@kmdreko @cdhowie Thank you two for your comments. I confirmed that both removing the where clause and using the higher rank trait bound fix the issue with the example provided. Unfortunately, neither of them seems to solve issues with my actual code, but it's good to know this might be a bug of the compiler.

@user4815162342 pretty sure there is but I can never find it when I'm looking for it

If you're still having this problem in more complicated code make sure you're not over constraining your lifetimes like this: Why does this mutable borrow live beyond its scope?

This is not a bug in the compiler, the compiler does exactly what it was requested here.
g() can, theoretically, use v for its whole lifetime ('a) since it is given a reference that long.
Normally, we would give g() a newer lifetime, shorter than f()'s 'a, but here we can't do that, since VecMutRef is only known to implement Length (which g() requires) for 'a. So we end up passing v with lifetime 'a twice, which is invalid.
If it is difficult to follow the above explanation, here is an example that will hopefully make it clearer:
use std::sync::Mutex;

struct VecMutRef<'a> {
    vec: &'a mut Vec<usize>,
}

trait Length {
    fn evil(self);
}

static ALL: Mutex<Vec<&'static mut Vec<usize>>> = Mutex::new(Vec::new());

impl Length for VecMutRef<'static> {
    fn evil(self) {
        ALL.lock().unwrap().push(self.vec);
    }
}

fn f<'a>(v: &'a mut Vec<usize>) -> usize
where
    VecMutRef<'a>: Length,
{
    let first = g(v);
    let second = g(v);
    first + second
}

fn g<'a>(v: &'a mut Vec<usize>) -> usize
where
    VecMutRef<'a>: Length,
{
    VecMutRef { vec: v }.evil();
    0
}

fn main() {
    f(Box::leak(Box::new(vec![1, 2, 3])));
}

The code was changed here, but the important part is that f() and g() signatures weren't changed at all. That means that if your code would compile, this would have to compile too. But this code is clearly invalid - it creates two duplicated &mut references in ALL.
A higher-ranked lifetime (for<'a> VecMutRef<'a>: Length) is the correct solution here. If it does not work, you can open a new question with your concrete use-case.

This does help me see how the compiler can get tongue-tied, but it still feels like it should be compilable since "VecMutRef is only known to implement Length for 'a" is not true in OP's code - both VecMutRef and Length are known types and thus the compiler should be able to reference impl<'a> Length for VecMutRef<'a> and realize that any 'a is valid. Having a VecMutRef<'a>: Length constraint should not lock-in the compiler into thinking 'a is the only option.

@kmdreko This part is because the compiler will always prefer constraints from where bounds, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/78172859/7884305. Usually you can solve this by fully specifying, but since those are lifetimes you cannot do that here.

I agree its the same sort of problem, but I'm in the camp of calling it a bug since it prevents otherwise valid code from compiling for arbitrary reasons.

Hi. Thanks for the detailed explanation! I think I now understand the issue. After some hassle, I managed to make the version with the higher-ranked lifetime bound work with my actual code. Previously, I was using const generic expressions, which are unstable features. For some reason, they were preventing the compiler from checking the higher-ranked lifetime bounds, but after removing the const generic expressions, my code compiles fine.
